# How to make a comment on a database, without the code getting translated?

Tags: php, view

eksample:
I want to make a database where admin can add "news article with code", where the code doesn't get translated, when posted on webpage.

So, someone post;

```
if (!isset($_GET['underside'])){
 include ('front.inc.php');
}else{
 include($_GET['underside']);
}
 ?>
```

(and it will be posted on the webpage, without being translated)
(the same technich as used on this page)

Comment: What do you mean, "translated"?  What is "this page" (did you forget a link)?

Answer (score 0):

Use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to read the file into a string, replace all special characters using [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) and then print the string using [echo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php).